# I write program that show the difference in percentage for Mobile Company Revenue

Tags: c

I write a program, but it is incomplete, that shows the difference in percentage for Mobile Company Revenue.
I should use an array average to hold for the past 3 years of sales revenue.
Sample output is given below Mobile Company Revenue Percentage

```
Enter Revenue for 2017: 100000 
Enter Revenue for 2018: 250000
Enter Revenue for 2018: 150000 
Enter Revenue for 2018: 150000 

Year % Remark
 Increase 150 2018 
Decrease 40- 2019 
 Unchange" 0,0 2020
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("--------------------------------------------------\n ");
    printf("Mobile Company Revenue Percentage\n ");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------\n ");
      int  i;
    float Revenue[4], sum = 0.0, avg;
    float rev1,rev2,rev3,rev4;
    printf("Enter Revenue for 2017: ");
        scanf("%f", &rev1);
    printf("Enter Revenue for 2018: ");
        scanf("%f", &rev2);
    printf("Enter Revenue for 2018: ");
        scanf("%f", &rev3);
    printf("Enter Revenue for 2018: ");
    scanf("%f", &rev4);

     

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        sum += Revenue[i];
    }

    avg = sum / sizeof(Revenue);
    printf("Average = %.2f", avg);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)` off-by-one error. The valid indexes for `Revenue` are `0` through `3`, not `4`. Additionally all elements of `Revenue` are uninitialized and attempting to access them with `sum += Revenue[i];` invokes *Undefined Behavior*. Always initialize your arrays, e.g. `float Revenue[4] = {0};`. You cannot use any use-input function correctly without ***checking the return***. Otherwise you have no way to know whether the input succeeded or failed. Your `avg` requires `sum / (sizeof Revenue / sizeof *Revenue`). Why `sizeof Revenue == 20`

Comment: It's time to learn about arrays and `for` loops. You're almost using them here, but it looks like you missed and declared a bunch of unrelated variables instead.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. What specific problem do you have that prevents you from progressing the code?

Comment: First of all, `float` is not safe as it causes a dip in terms of performance and is less precise than `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is apparent you are having a bit of trouble. As noted above, in my comment you have number of issues and invoke *Undefined Behavior* attempting to use array values with automatic storage duration white the values are indeterminate (uninitialized). The problem arises due to your use of *Magic Numbers* in your code. This contributes to your loop limit being off-by-one (too many).

To avoid using *Magic Numbers* compute what you need and assign the value to a variable. For example, you need to number of elements in `Revenue`. That can be determined by taking the size of the array divided by the size of the first element.

```
    int  nelem = sizeof Revenue/sizeof *Revenue;
```

(**note:** the proper type would be `size_t`, but C allows an `int` for the return as well)

With the number of elements set, you can then loop the appropriate number of times, and compute the average with the appropriate divisor, e.g.

```
    for (i = 0; i < nelem; i++)
        sum += Revenue[i];
    avg = sum / nelem;
    
    printf ("\nAverage = %.2f\n", avg);
```

Now let's look at input. You cannot use any user-input function correctly unless you check the return. Otherwise, you have no way to determine whether the input succeeded or failed. Further, it is completely valid for the user to cancel the input by generating a manual `EOF` (with <kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> on windows). So you must handle that case. You also need to remove the `'\n'` left in `stdin` by `scanf()` in case the next input in your program is with an input function that does not discard leading whitespace.

Since you will be taking more than one `float`, it would make sense to write a short function to handle the validation for you. So each time you need a `float`, you simply call the function. You can accomplish that while taking the prompt to display as a parameter to the function. You could do something like:

```
/* display prompt and return float (exit on manual EOF) */
float getfloat (const char *prompt)
{
    float f = 0;
    
    while (1) {     /* loop continually until valid float provided by user */
        if (prompt)                             /* prompt if not NULL */
            fputs (prompt, stdout);
        int rtn = scanf ("%f", &f);             /* read float, save return */
        if (rtn == EOF) {                       /* check for manual EOF */
            puts ("(user canceled input)");
            exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        empty_stdin();                          /* empty to end of line */
        if (rtn == 1)                           /* if good input, break loop */
            break;
        
        fputs ("  error: invalid float input.\n", stderr);  /* handle error */
    }
    
    return f;       /* return float value */
}
```

Note, the function loops continually until the user provides a valid `float` or cancels the input. That is how you should approach each user-input. Don't allow the user to provide input input without handling that error and ensuring your get the input your program requires.

The `empty_stdin()` helper function called in `getfloat()` above, simply discards any extraneous characters in `stdin` up to the next `'\n'` or `EOF` whichever occurs first. That way if the user enters something like `"Lots of money"` instead of a valid amount, that is removed from `stdin` before your next attempted input. Nothing more is required than:

```
/* simple helper to clear stdin */
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

Now your `main()` function reduces to a bit of readable code that accomplishes get four `float` values and computing the average, e.g.

```
int main (void) {
    
    float Revenue[4] = {0}, sum = 0.0, avg = 0;
    int  i, nelem = sizeof Revenue/sizeof *Revenue;
    
    puts ("--------------------------------------------------\n"
          "Mobile Company Revenue Percentage\n"
          "--------------------------------------------------\n ");
    
    Revenue[0] = getfloat ("Enter Revenue for 2017: ");
    Revenue[1] = getfloat ("Enter Revenue for 2018: ");
    Revenue[2] = getfloat ("Enter Revenue for 2019: ");
    Revenue[3] = getfloat ("Enter Revenue for 2020: ");

    for (i = 0; i < nelem; i++)
        sum += Revenue[i];
    avg = sum / nelem;
    
    printf ("\nAverage = %.2f\n", avg);
}
```

(I made up years since you had `2018` listed for 3 of the 4 years)

You only need one call to an output function to output as many lines as you need. If there are no conversion required (e.g. `"%f"`, etc..), then there is no need to use the variadic `printf()` function. Simply use `puts()` (or `fputs()` if you need end-of-line control.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/mobileco
--------------------------------------------------
Mobile Company Revenue Percentage
--------------------------------------------------

Enter Revenue for 2017: 100
Enter Revenue for 2018: 200
Enter Revenue for 2019: 300
Enter Revenue for 2020: 400

Average = 250.00
```

If bad input is provide by the user, the program will not accept it, e.g.:

```
$ ./bin/mobileco
--------------------------------------------------
Mobile Company Revenue Percentage
--------------------------------------------------

Enter Revenue for 2017: A whole lot of $Money$ :)
  error: invalid float input.
Enter Revenue for 2017: 100
Enter Revenue for 2018: 200
Enter Revenue for 2019: three-hundred
  error: invalid float input.
Enter Revenue for 2019: 300
Enter Revenue for 2020: 400

Average = 250.00
```

---

**Computing Percent-Change in Revenue Between Years**

In response to your comment below, you can compute the *percent increase* or *percent decrease* from the average revenue by using the percent change formula. To compute the value you have an `original` and `new` value. In computing the change from average, your `original` value is the average, and the `new` value is the revenue for the year. You need to apply either the *percent-increase* formula if the revenue exceeds the average, or the *percent-decrease* formula if the revenue is below average.

The formulas for *percent increase* and *percent decrease* are:

```
pct_increase = (new - original) / original * 100;
```

and

```
pct_decrease = (original - new) / original * 100;
```

You can simply create a *percent change* function and check the `original` and `new` values and apply the correct formula and return that value. For example:

```
/* percent change between new_value and orig_value */
float percentchg (const float new_value, const float orig_value)
{
    if (new_value < orig_value)
        return (orig_value - new_value) / orig_value * 100.;
    
    return (new_value - orig_value) / orig_value * 100.;
}
```

(**note:** since `new` is a C++ keyword, it is better to avoid using it in your code, in case your code is included as part of a C++ program later -- even though there are ways to make it work)

Then in `main()` to compute the percent change for each year, you would do:

```
    ...
    printf ("\nAverage = %.2f\n\n", avg);
    
    for (i = 0; i < nelem; i++)
        printf ("year %d revenue: %.2f%% (%s) from average\n", i + 1,
                percentchg (Revenue[i], avg),
                Revenue[i] < avg ? "decrease" : "increase");
```

(**note:** a *ternary* is used to determine whether to output `"decrease"` or `"increase"` as part of the output. A ternary is just a short hand for `if (condition) { if_true } else { if_false }` for which the syntax is:

```
condition ? if_true : if_false
```

which you can see included as a parameter to the `printf()` function supplying input to the `"%s"` format specifier)

**New Example Output**

```
$ ./bin/mobileco
--------------------------------------------------
Mobile Company Revenue Percentage
--------------------------------------------------

Enter Revenue for 2017: 100
Enter Revenue for 2018: 200
Enter Revenue for 2019: 300
Enter Revenue for 2020: 400

Average = 250.00

year 1 revenue: 60.00% (decrease) from average
year 2 revenue: 20.00% (decrease) from average
year 3 revenue: 20.00% (increase) from average
year 4 revenue: 60.00% (increase) from average
```

---

**Complete Code**

If you would help to see the compete code after the update, that is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* simple helper to clear stdin */
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

/* display prompt and return float (exit on manual EOF) */
float getfloat (const char *prompt)
{
    float f = 0;
    
    while (1) {     /* loop continually until valid float provided by user */
        if (prompt)                             /* prompt if not NULL */
            fputs (prompt, stdout);
        int rtn = scanf ("%f", &f);             /* read float, save return */
        if (rtn == EOF) {                       /* check for manual EOF */
            puts ("(user canceled input)");
            exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        empty_stdin();                          /* empty to end of line */
        if (rtn == 1)                           /* if good input, break loop */
            break;
        
        fputs ("  error: invalid float input.\n", stderr);  /* handle error */
    }
    
    return f;       /* return float value */
}

/* percent change between new_value and orig_value */
float percentchg (const float new_value, const float orig_value)
{
    if (new_value < orig_value)
        return (orig_value - new_value) / orig_value * 100.;
    
    return (new_value - orig_value) / orig_value * 100.;
}

int main (void) {
    
    float Revenue[4] = {0}, sum = 0.0, avg = 0;
    int  i, nelem = sizeof Revenue/sizeof *Revenue;
    
    puts ("--------------------------------------------------\n"
          "Mobile Company Revenue Percentage\n"
          "--------------------------------------------------\n ");
    
    Revenue[0] = getfloat ("Enter Revenue for 2017: ");
    Revenue[1] = getfloat ("Enter Revenue for 2018: ");
    Revenue[2] = getfloat ("Enter Revenue for 2019: ");
    Revenue[3] = getfloat ("Enter Revenue for 2020: ");

    for (i = 0; i < nelem; i++)
        sum += Revenue[i];
    avg = sum / nelem;
    
    printf ("\nAverage = %.2f\n\n", avg);
    
    for (i = 0; i < nelem; i++)
        printf ("year %d revenue: %.2f%% (%s) from average\n", i + 1,
                percentchg (Revenue[i], avg),
                Revenue[i] < avg ? "decrease" : "increase");
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: thanks , how to shows the difference in percentage for Mobile Company Revenue??

Comment: Due you mean for each year, like between 2017-2018, and then 2018-2019, etc..? Meaning once you have the average, you would want to know the percent-difference for each year?

Comment: @Fedaa - I have updated the answer to include the percent-change calculations.